# Disable scroll of recyclerview (inside viewpager) untill its fully visible (viewpager is in scrollview)

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview

I have a layout similar to the one shown in image below.

[Layout Explained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPsWC.jpg)

```
<ScrollView>
   <LinearLayout>
    ...
   </LinearLayout>
 <ViewPager>
</ScrollView>
```

`ViewPager` has a height equal to the height of screen below `ActionBar`.

While scrolling, when half of the `viewPager` is visible.. Vertical scroll of `RecylerView` of fragment in `ViewPager` interferes with the main scroll of `ScrollView`.

I want a solution that makes sure the scroll of `RecyclerView` inside viewpager is disabled untill the viewpager is fully visible.

Main.xml

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/secondary_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/secondary_margin"
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view">

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <include layout="@layout/home_deals_slider" />

            <include layout="@layout/top_selling_slider" />

            ...
            <TabLayout>

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
               android:id="@+id/fragments_view_pager"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_below="@+id/fragments_view_pager_tab" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Fragment.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/staggered_grid_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    </RelativeLayout>
    ...
```

Comment: Added the layouts, Main.xml contains ScrollView and a ViewPager inside Fragment.xml contains RecyclerView

Comment: can u use cardview in recyclerview ? change your fragment.xml recylcerview no need any framelayout or relavtivelayout .

Comment: how does changing recylerview to cardview will help, cardviews are already being used to display items in recyclerview

Comment: cardview are use just display item of recyclerview . post that code of xml how can you display your item

Comment: i dont think that is related to the problem i am addressing.. I want a solution where i can enable/disable the scroll of recyclerview based on if it is fully visible or not

Comment: remove your cardview and just try its workfine for me . just try it is not final solution .